# dirname() in C: is the manual wrong?

Tags: c, dirname

Citing [the manual](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dirname) here:

> The  functions  dirname() and basename() break a null-terminated
>   pathname string into directory and filename components.  In the usual
>   case, **dirname() returns the string up to, but not including, the final
>   '/'**, and basename() returns the component following the final '/'. 
>   Trailing '/' characters are not counted as part of the pathname.

And later on, you have this little table:

```
path         dirname    basename
"/usr/lib"    "/usr"    "lib"
"/usr/"       "/"       "usr"        // wat?
"usr"         "."       "usr"
"/"           "/"       "/"
"."           "."       "."
".."          "."       ".."
```

Why is `dirname( "/usr/")` returning `"/"` and not `"/usr"` ?
The sentence in the manual tells me I should get `/usr` as a result.
I tested the actual result in a dummy program and it behaves just like the manual says.

```
#include <libgen.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    const char *mydir="/usr/";
    char *dummy  = strdup( mydir );
    char *dummy2 = strdup( mydir );

    char *dname = dirname( dummy );
    char *bname = basename( dummy2 );


    printf("mydir: '%s', dname: '%s', bname: '%s'\n", mydir, dname, bname);

    free( dummy );
    free( dummy2 );

    return 0;
}


$ ./test  
mydir: '/usr/', dname: '/', bname: 'usr'
```

Now, what I would expect would be:

```
path         dirname    basename
"/usr/"       "/usr"       ""        // more consistent?
```

So.. anybody understands what's going on here?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Trailing '/' characters are not counted as part of the pathname.

Hence "/usr/" is the same as "/usr", which might denote a file or a directory with name (directory entry named) `usr` in the directory `/`. The function `dirname` returns the parent directory of the path. The parent directory of `/usr` is `/`. Seems entirely consistent.

Comment: +1 you got the key point and cited it. FYI there's also an Austin Group interpretation for a related issue #612: http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=612

Answer (score 4):

A directory is also a file.  `usr` is of course the basename of the file `/usr`.  This follows the manual precisely - in `/usr`, the root-`/` is the final `/` and `usr` is what follows it, hence is the basename.

As for `/usr/` v. `/usr`, I suspect this is because the final `/` is always swallowed and this is specified somewhere else or falls under the "in the usual case" qualification.  Or else `/usr///` and `/usr///////////` would refer to wildly different entities...